# Center and bottom align a full list (again)

Tags: html, css, navigation, center

First, I realize that there are similar questions already posted on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions presented is working for me. I still can't aligned my navigation properly--to the center and the bottom of a div called "header".

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dsguffey/g3Rg2/

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="header">
    <ul>
      <li>
      <p class="quote">Site quote,</p>
      <p class="quote">goes here</p>
      </li>         
      <li>Music</li>
      <li>Games</li>
      <li>Writing</li>
      <li>Art</li>
      <li>About me</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="writing_page">
    <div id="writing_box">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="footer" style="text-align:center;">
  <span style="text-align:center;color:white;">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  height:100%;
}   
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#footer{
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  bottom:0px;
  background-color:#000000;
}
/*navigation*/
#header{
  position:absolute;
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#000000;
}
#header ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
#header li{
  display:inline-block;
  color:goldenrod;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  font-size:10pt;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:'Segoe Script';
}
.quote{
  text-align:right;
  font-size:18pt; 
}
/*Content*/
#writing_page{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:100px;
  bottom:100px;
  background-image:url('./images/bg.png');
  color:black;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

I can get the nav menu list to center horizontally (which is how it is on the fiddle now), but anything I do to try to get it to center horizontally makes it so that it will no longer align bottom and vice versa! I've tried turning #header, ul, and/or li into display:table-cell. Also, I've tried to use position:absolute and bottom:0px on UL. I've tried using auto margins, vertical-align: bottom, vertical-align:text-bottom, and everything else I can think of. I've tried forcing the heights of ul and li to 100px or placing the list inside a table with set height and width. It's driving me insane. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: In addition to the CSS above, there's also a reset in the fiddle which solves some of the formatting issues. I omitted it here for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution for you...using a bit of CSS you supplied in your jsfiddle. I changed `position` on `#header` to `relative`. Then, set a few properties on `#header ul`. Used `position:absolute` and `bottom:0` to align the `ul` to the bottom of the `#header`. Then, set `left:50%` to move the left edge to the center. Set a fixed `width:680px` (feel free to adjust) and a `margin-left:-340px` (which is negative 1/2 the width, so adjust if you change the width). I also removed some of the extra properties that weren't really doing anything. Hope this helps.

```
#header{
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#000000;
}
#header ul{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 680px;
    margin-left: -340px;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Update:** Why `#header` has `position:relative`.

Absolute positioned elements will be positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than `static`. If none is found, it uses the `html` container. In this case, you want the `ul` to be positioned `absolute` but relative to the parent `#header` element. Hope that answers the question. Don't be afraid to play around with the values...especially in the interest of furthering your knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. I understand all the changes you made except for one thing. Why does the header position need to be relative?

Comment: I updated the solution to respond to your question about the `#header` element. If the solution worked, don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer. It will benefit both of us. :)